# subquery of HQL return nothing

Tags: sql, hive, return, subquery

I am **running the following HQL:**

```
hive>select period,count(*) from
(select case when hour(a.first_time)>=21 and hour(a.first_time)<24 then'21-24'
             when hour(a.first_time)>=12 and hour(a.first_time)<21 then'12-21'
             else '0-12'
             end as period
             from longyuan_web.tv_log as a ) p1
group by period;
```

**But nothing returned**, can anyone tell me why?
I expect the output will be like this:

```
0-12    34000
12-21   12000
21-24   32000
```

thank u so much!

Comment: Nothing, as in zero rows, or nothing as in the count(*) is wrong or zero.

Comment: maybe i should change 'select period,count(*) from' to 'select count(period),i think this might be work@JoeLove

Comment: Simply run a query `select hour(a.first_time) as hr, count(*) from longyuan_web.tv_log group by hr;`. This will give you the actual count and will help you to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: @JoeLove is right,i have found exactly the problem,count(*) is actually zero,because i set the Wrong Where condition inside the SUBQUERY which i didn't specify here,the grammar is right,it should give me what i want

Comment: thanks @Ambrish you are right,i should do that to locate the problem